# Karma output unreadable due to huge traceback

Tags: javascript, jasmine, firebase, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I've been experimenting with using Karma with Jasmine to run unit tests for my project.  But the output reported by Karma includes these giant stack traces that make it very hard to read the output.  Here is a sample of the output I'm seeing, copy-pasted from my terminal:  https://gist.github.com/JesseAldridge/5946d4ec299ed1f85cfb

Does anyone know of a way to make this output more readable?

Note that a lot of those lines are coming from Firebase.  Maybe there's some way to make Firebase produce less verbose tracebacks?  (Er, something along those lines anyway.)

I tried tee'ing the output to a file, but then I end up getting the progress line repeated every other line in the file.  Turning off the progress line is an option, but I'd really like to be able to monitor my test progress.  I also have to turn off syntax coloring to avoid junk characters being output to the text file, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the mocha reporter helped mitigate the issue significantly:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha-reporter

Comment: Whoa, thanks for the suggestion.  I just added mocha and am really enjoying it.